# an example of stochastic matrix not derived from a unitary matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, quantum-computation, quantum-information

[image]

I solved (a) but cannot find an example for (b). Could anyone show me a stochastic matrix not derived from a unitary matrix?

Answer (score 6):

this is a classical question, and the answer is well known by specialists. So let's just give a link for a [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379578900228) and the example mentioned there, that is attributed to J. Hoffman: a $3\times 3$ matrix, the average of two permutation matrices, that does not come from a unitary matrix

$$\frac{P_{\sigma} + P_{\sigma^{-1}}}{2} =\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1& 0 & 1 \\
1& 1& 0 
\end{matrix}
\right) $$

I suppose checking that is a good exercise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can't work out how this matrix does not come from a unitary matrix... Could you explain me more? or at least a hint?

Comment: @Keith: Can you make the square roots of the first $2$ rows orthogonal by some phase change? Not really